# How do I print the output really fast and fix the repeat print pattern, also a division issue for output?

Tags: python, math, printing, numbers, division

While I print using this python37 code it repeats till the end and its slow.  I really need it to print super fast.  Also I would like to divide the **first number it finds before the colon** and output the number that it is associated with **after the colon**.

For instance the program finds this ratio pair ( 8978:1445580) in the set after going through an amount of numbers and I decided to divide it like this 8978/8978 then the output should print (1445580).  Or maybe it just matches 8978 and prints (1445580) as the output.

Is this possible?  It does seem programmable, but my skills are a little weak in this area and I could use some help.

**Thanks very much for any help!** :)

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    while True:
        list_numbers={}
        a = int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
        b = int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))

        y = int(input(' Enter y start range: '))
        n = int(input(' Enter n end range: '))

        for x in range(y,n):
            list_numbers.update({a*x: b*x})
            print(list_numbers)
```

Comment: Why you have a ```while true```?

Comment: I use that so I can repeat the process in the terminal.  After the output.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out the whole dictionary `list_numbers` on every pass of the loop instead of printing just the new values. That would probably take a while if the dictionary becomes big.

You could instead just print out the new values being added:

```
for x in range(y,n):
    new_values = {a*x: b*x}
    list_numbers.update(new_values)
    print(new_values)
```

Or alternatively, wait until the loop finishes and print out the whole thing:

```
for x in range(y,n):
    list_numbers.update({a*x: b*x})

print(list_numbers)
```

If you do the latter, your code can be simplified:

```
while True:
    a = int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
    b = int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))

    y = int(input(' Enter y start range: '))
    n = int(input(' Enter n end range: '))

    list_numbers = {a*x: b*x for x in range(y,n)}
    print(list_numbers)
```

That's just the improvement I see here for printing more efficiently, I actually don't know what you mean by your division problem (and it seems like a subject for a different question entirely)

Comment: Thanks ofer Saden the printing is much faster, but I still need that division output to work in a major way.  I'm on to a major break through in mathematics. :)

Comment: @TomE.O'Neil do name me in your research paper :) But seriously - ask another question about your division - detail the problem properly

Answer (score 0):

As someone told you before, printing afer the computation is faster.
The mathematics goes inside a function, I think it's better than "while True" to keep your code running.
And I've just changed the inputs for fixed variables for testing purposes only.
In both functions (the one with your code and mine) you get out 100 results (printed lists lenght). You miss nothing here, but buy more time :-)

import timeit

```
#your code
def code_timed():

    list_numbers={}

    a = 3 #int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
    b = 5 #int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))

    y = 500 # int(input(' Enter y start range: '))
    n = 600 # int(input(' Enter n end range: '))


    for x in range(y,n):
        list_numbers.update({a*x: b*x})
        print(list_numbers)     


elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_timed, number=100)/100
print(elapsed_time) 
0.8021428676611905

# mine
def code_timed():

    faster_list=[]

    a = 3 #int(input(' Enter 1st number for ratio calculation: '))
    b = 5 #int(input(' Enter 2nd number for ratio calculation: '))

    y = 500 # int(input(' Enter y start range: '))
    n = 600 # int(input(' Enter n end range: '))


    for x in range(y,n):
        faster_list.append({a*x: b*x})


    print(faster_list[0]) #to get out of the '[]'


elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_timed, number=100)/100
print(elapsed_time)     
0.004112908859074196
```